# nskvopendingnotification error in objective-c

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I have the following problem

during **abstraction** i have **encapsulated** a class in objective c which allows me to change a rectangles size and position over an underlying image.
I use this class as in some situations each slightly different.
In one i need to ensure a minimum and maximum size in a other the rect must be a square. 
So i observe the value set by the user and check it against rules by using the objective-c methods:

```
[rectDrawer addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"value" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
```

In this method i check the constraints. But when i want to correct a invalid value and write it back it comes to that problem with "EXC_BAD_ACCESS" exception

I also tried following to avoid the exception but this does not help

```
[rectDrawer removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"value"];
rectDrawer.value = _value;
[rectDrawer addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"value" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];
```

is there a possible solution for this

Comment: Do you also remove the observation in `dealloc`? In general, with KVO, you need to be very careful that you don't add an observer twice and that you remove all observers before they're deallocated. Perhaps there are still other objects registered as observers that don't exist anymore, and one of them is triggered by changing the property in your observer method. Enabling zombies could help with debugging this.

Comment: Hey, object and observer are living when the exception occurs. it happens when i edit the rect on screen and a constraint want to limit a value. Also there is no other object which observes the value only the calling class which wants to regulate the value.

Comment: You might still want to turn on zombies. `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` is usually the result of messages being sent to deallocated objects.

Comment: Having zombies already enabled the debugger gives me no output. also Diagnostics is no help as the app is immediately crashing and also no output is there.